# Python: split sentence from file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file data.txt like that:

```
<<a
<<t This is a title 01
/t>>
<<c
This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.
This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.
/c>>
/a>>
<<a
<<t This is a title 02
/t>>
<<c
This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.
This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.
/c>>
/a>>
```

I want read file and split each sentence to a list like:

```
[[This is a title 01],[This is a sentence.],[This is a sentence.]...[This is a title 02],[This is a sentence.]...]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hello! What have you tried so far on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following-

```
result = []
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    if "This is a title" in line:
      cleaned_line = line.lstrip('<<t').strip()
      result.append(cleaned_line)
    elif line.startswith("This is a sentence"):
      sentence_list = line.split('.')
      for _ in sentence_list:
        result.append(_)
```

**How this works?**
Open the file, iterate it line by line.
To extract the Titles. strip `<<t` and whitespaces.
To extract the sentences just split the line string at periods(.). And then append everything into a `result` list.
EDIT:
NOTE: You will eventually have a list of strings. Since you are new to Python, i will leave it as an exercise for you to convert a list of strings to a list of lists. It should be incredibly simple.